# Access Device Storage Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, debugging, xamarin

I'm looking for a way to see my app contents on the device the app is being ran on using Xamarin iOS. I would like to do this while debugging the app.

On android this can be viewed through DDMS and then Device File Storage so I'm looking for the same or similar process for Xamarin iOS.

I have also researched and found that you can do this using XCode so I'm hoping its possible through Xamarin also.

Device is iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "want to see contents"? Like a file manager app? Or remotely? Or while debugging the app?

Comment: While debugging. Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your app will be saved locally on your mac when debugging, But the location is dynamic and abit hard to find. I use the following tool and it makes it very easy to access all the data I need. https://simpholders.com/